# How to return pointer to const from static function?

Tags: c++, static, constants, member-functions

```
static const Function* Get...();
```

Why can't I return pointer to a const from static member function? Or can I?

Where

```
typedef void Function(Object * object, HandlerAction action);
```

I just don't want to let caller to alter function pointer he got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to return in your code is a pointer to a constant non-member function (but this is not a valid construct, only member functions can be constant).

What you want to do is to return a constant pointer to a function, which would be written like this:

```
static Function * const Get...();
```

`const` always applies to the type to its immediate left; unless it's the first thing (which it is in your case, as `static` is no type and therefore cannot be made `const` - in that case it applies to the type to its immediate right, which is `Function` in your case, so the function type itself, not the pointer.